# Did the "close as dup" auto-comment change?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I was looking at [RSpec: how to test if a method was called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262309/rspec-test-to-see-if-a-method-was-called) and s both a close-as-dup vote and a comment pointing to another question. However, instead of the usual comment format, it had "Check here: ..." (see below)

Did the close-dup-auto-comment language change? Is that some other comment and the close-dup-auto-comment not get posted for some reason?

[image]

Comment: Or (s)he deleted the auto-comment and added a new comment. (edit: (s)he doesn't even have enough reputation to vote for closure, so I guess that someone else voted to close)

Answer (score 1):

The person who posted the comment does not have enough rep to cast close votes, they have ~1100, and you need 3000. Probably he/she flagged it as a duplicate, someone close voted it, and perhaps they deleted the comments because kdeisz's comment was already there

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but I wanted to point that although there are now two votes to close-as-dup, the referenced question in the comment deals with a different matter and isn't really a duplicate (imho)!